# HayStack error on Django Log

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I've gone through the error logs from Apache named `error_django.log` and found my Haystack hasn't been properly configured.

I've gone through the docs and haven't found anything that's wrongfully configured.

Here's my settings file

```
ENABLE_SEARCH_STATISTICS = True


DJANGO_MEMCACHED_REQUIRE_STAFF = True


SERIALIZATION_MODULES = {
    'json': 'wadofstuff.django.serializers.json'
}

HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.xapian_backend.XapianEngine',
        'PATH': '/home/kbuzz/xapian_index',
        'BATCH_SIZE': 100,
    },
}

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '/home/kbuzz/memcached.sock',
    }
}

CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS = "default"
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 360
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = "kb"
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ANONYMOUS_ONLY = True

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.markup',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.redirects',
    'django.contrib.humanize',

    'autocomplete_light',
    'memcache_status',
    'djangorestframework',
    'haystack',
    'lamusoftware.generic',
    'mptt',
    'bootstrapform',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
    'south',
    'oauth2client',
    'articles',
    'banners',
    'common',
    'directory',
    'events',
    'galleries',
    'marketplace',
    'movies',
    'pages',
    'profiles',
    'search',
    'stats',
    'minidetector',
    'mobile',
    'reports',
    'favorites',
    'braces',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'wordofmouth',
    'ckeditor',
    'django_mobile',
    'debug_toolbar',

)

#SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES = {
 #   'auth': 'profiles.authmigrations',
#}

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PATCH_SETTINGS = False
```

and the error log

```
[Fri Oct 16 10:02:23 2015] [error] Internal Server Error: /biz-directory/category/directory/retail/shopping-malls
[Fri Oct 16 10:02:23 2015] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Oct 16 10:02:23 2015] [error]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 92, in get_response
[Fri Oct 16 10:02:23 2015] [error]     response = middleware_method(request)
[Fri Oct 16 10:02:23 2015] [error]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/newrelic-2.44.0.36/newrelic/hooks/framework_django.py", line 220, in wrapper
[Fri Oct 16 10:02:23 2015] [error]     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
[Fri Oct 16 10:02:23 2015] [error]   File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/kb/kb/middleware/log_ip_middleware.py", line 29, in process_request
[Fri Oct 16 10:02:23 2015] [error]     user.save()
[Fri Oct 16 10:02:23 2015] [error]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/base.py", line 546, in save
[Fri Oct 16 10:02:23 2015] [error]     force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
[Fri Oct 16 10:02:23 2015] [error]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/base.py", line 570, in save_base
[Fri Oct 16 10:02:23 2015] [error]     update_fields=update_fields)
[Fri Oct 16 10:02:23 2015] [error]   File "/home/kbuzz/lib/python2.7/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 170, in send
[Fri Oct 16 10:02:23 2015] [error]     response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
[Fri Oct 16 10:02:23 2015] [error]   File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/kb/src/django-haystack/haystack/models.py", line 230, in load_indexes
[Fri Oct 16 10:02:23 2015] [error]     ui.setup_indexes()
[Fri Oct 16 10:02:23 2015] [error]   File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/kb/src/django-haystack/haystack/utils/loading.py", line 268, in setup_indexes
[Fri Oct 16 10:02:23 2015] [error]     self.build()
[Fri Oct 16 10:02:23 2015] [error]   File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/django/kb/src/django-haystack/haystack/utils/loading.py", line 203, in build
[Fri Oct 16 10:02:23 2015] [error]     raise ImproperlyConfigured("Model '%s' has more than one 'SearchIndex`` handling it. Please exclude either '%s' or '%s' using the 'HAYSTACK_EXCLUDED_INDEXES' setting." % (model, self.indexes[model], index))
[Fri Oct 16 10:02:23 2015] [error] ImproperlyConfigured: Model '<class 'articles.models.Article'>' has more than one 'SearchIndex`` handling it. Please exclude either '<articles.search_indexes.ArticleIndex object at 0x7f5ce737b4c8>' or '<articles.search_indexes.ArticleIndex object at 0x7f5ce6da66d0>' using the 'HAYSTACK_EXCLUDED_INDEXES' setting.
```

Answer (score 0):

As in the [doc](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.4.0/tutorial.html#creating-searchindexes) in haystack,

> You generally create a unique SearchIndex for each type of Model you
> wish to index

Maybe you have defined two or more SearchIndexs for the `articles.model.Article`. Please check `get_model` in your SearchIndex.